# Asynchronously stopping a loop from outside node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, exception

I am using node.js 14 and currently have a loop that is made by a recursive function and a setTimeout, something like this:

```
this.timer = null;

async recursiveLoop() {
   //Do Stuff
   this.timer = setTimeout(this.recursiveLoop.bind(this), rerun_time);
}
```

But sometimes this loop gets stuck and I want it to automatically notice it, clean up and restart. So I tried doing something like this:

```
this.timer = null;

async recursiveLoop() {
   this.long_timer = setTimeout(() => throw new Error('Taking too long!'), tooLong);
   //Do Stuff
   this.timer = setTimeout(this.recursiveLoop.bind(this), rerun_time);
}

main() {
  //Do other asynchronous stuff
  recursiveLoop()
    .then()
    .catch((e) => {
       console.log(e.message);
       cleanUp();
       recursiveLoop();
    }
}
```

I can't quite debug where it gets stuck, because it seems quite random and the program runs on a virtual machine. I still couldn't reproduce it locally.

This makeshift solution, instead of working, keeps crashing the whole node.js aplication, and now I am the one stuck. I have the constraint of working with node.js 14, without using microservices, and I never used child process before. I am a complete beginner. Please help me!

Comment: What does "loop gets stuck" actually mean?  What exactly do you observe or measure or see?  Is there any actual real code in this loop because what you show us doesn't actually do anything.  In fact, it doesn't even log anything.  If there is real code involved, then that's probably where the real problem is and we'd need to see that to help you fix your actual problem.  ***Please show us your REAL code.***  Questions that just show scaffolding or pseudo-code are very hard or impossible to answer.

Comment: A `setTimeout()` can be stopped with `clearTimeout(timer)`.  Really not sure what else you're asking for.

Comment: A `throw` in a `setTimeout()` callback will not do anything useful as it just throws to an empty stack and therefore nothing can catch it.

Comment: Where'd you go?  Trying to help, but you're not responding to clarifying questions.

Comment: I am not really worried about the getting stuck part. What I really wanted to solve is the not noticing it. I can't disclose the real code because it is company owned. The scaffolding is just to show that there is a loop made by a setTimeout. I wanted the program to notice that it is stuck and then throw an error that would restart it.
The problem with this approach is as you said, the setTimeout throws to an empty stack and crashes the program because it cant be caught.

Comment: I don't think I can help without real code.  This isn't a generic issue.  It's an issue specific to your actual code.

Comment: Crashing the whole program is not amazing, because this is a monolithic project, and the other parts usually are working fine. Just this loop malfunctions from time to time. It is a very big and complex loop also. So management decided to work on the why later. I just have to figure out how can we notice and restart the loop cleanly. I thought about just restarting a new loop, but that can have devastating consequences since the memory used by each loop might pile up and crash the whole machine.

Comment: I thought about wrapping the loop in a cancelable function and just cancel the loop function and then restart it. But I am unsure how could I actually do it if it is stuck. So killing the loop stack with an error was what I thought possible, except it kills the whole program...

Comment: What does "loop stuck" even mean?  If the loop isn't running, isn't it already stopped?  What else do you want to do to stop it?  Sorry, but after all this and still no real code to look at a real problem, this question still is unclear.

Comment: If you have a black box of code (which is all you've given us) with no way to detect errors on it and you just want to know when it is no longer generating results, you can put it in a child_process and ask the code in the child process to send you a message every time it runs an iteration.  Then, in your main process, you can set a timer that resets itself every time it gets one of these "health" messages from the child.  If the timer fires without getting a health message, then the child must be "stuck".  You can kill the child process at that point and restart it.

Comment: But, that is a giant hack.  You should FIX the code that gets stuck or at least understand what's going on.  Probably you're either leaking memory, file handles, database handles, running code that uses locks and messes up or there are unhandled errors happening.  All are indications of code that should be fixed.

Comment: I was really trying to avoid child process, but I guess it IS the way. The code will be fixed later, but we really wanted to stop the bleeding as fast as possible and then find and fix this bug. Yours was a huge help, thank you so much. I will get on stopping the bleeding to buy some time to fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a black box of code (which is all you've given us) with no way to detect errors on it and you just want to know when it is no longer generating results, you can put it in a child_process and ask the code in the child process to send you a message every time it runs an iteration. Then, in your main process, you can set a timer that resets itself every time it gets one of these "health" messages from the child. If the timer fires without getting a health message, then the child must be "stuck" because you haven't heard from it within your timeout time. You can then kill the child process at that point and restart it.

But, that is a giant hack. You should FIX the code that gets stuck or at least understand what's going on. Probably you're either leaking memory, file handles, database handles, running code that uses locks and messes up or there are unhandled errors happening. All are indications of code that should be fixed.